# WP 8.1 (RT) issue with MessageDialog on device/emulator with Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal

I recently finished application which is using Universal Apps 8.1 technology. Now I'm testing my application on device with Windows 10 and also on emulator on version 10.0.10586.0 and I have big problem with MessageDialog.

I have simple app Universal app 8.1 which reproduces problem. Here is the XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox />
    <PasswordBox />
    <Button Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

and there is an event in code-behind:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("a");
    await msgDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

When user clicks on inputs, everything is fine. But when users taps on button, MessageDialog is displayed, and after that, things get messy and inputs stops to working properly. For example LostFocus event is not firing and the inputs stays in focus state.

When you put this code in UWP project and deploy to Windows 10 mobile device/emulator, everything is fine.

Any ideas?

P.S. ContentDialog is working properly, but it isn't support Windows 8.1.

### EDIT:

Here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F03F4A20B9FFCD!24843&authkey=!AHPXxcxSoPJnw3U&ithint=file%2czip is zip with sample app and screenshots.

I've tested this on Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 on emulator with version 10.0.10586 and also on device with the same version.

This is my test scenario:

1) Tap on TextBox

2) Tap on PasswordBox

3) Tap anywhere on the screen

4) Result (1.png)

- TextBox is not selected
- PasswordBox is not selected
- Keyboard is hidden

5) Tap on button

6) Close MessageDialog using close button

7) Tap on TextBox

8) Tap on PasswordBox

10) Tap anywhere on the screen

11) Result (2.png)

- TextBox is selected (sometimes)
- PasswordBox is selected
- Keyboard is shown

Comment: I tested your code both in a UWP project and a  Universal 8.1 app, my OS's version is windows 10 10586.11, and my mobile emulator's version is 10.0.10240.0. I used both local machine and mobile emulator to test this two project, your problem didn't reappear by me, they act the same way. The focus is at fisrt on the `TextBox` as default, you can get foucs on inputs by clicking them, and when you click the button, the both inputs lost focus and become gray, close the message will not let the inputs get focus until you click them.

Comment: @panda - I've added solution and test scenario which reproduces error for my on diffrent computers, emulators and devices.

Comment: @JerzyPiechowiak I don't have any idea on how to solve this. But I could in fact reproduce your error, and using the version 10.0.10240.0 it doesn't happen. I would say it is a bug in the version 10.0.10586.0

Comment: @Menses - thanks:) I'm not alone:) I don't know if there will be new release in the near future.. I switched to 'Insider fast' and the problem is still present. In this month, the OS is going to public and there is high probability that many (all?) apps that are using MessageDialogs and inputs will be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version of OS pushed to Insider resolved the issue.
Build 10.586.29.